# Not getting ID from another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Basically, I have a program where you have to input a student's ID, first and last name and their teacher's first and last name. When the user does and hits submit, the server query's into my MySQL database and gets the ID of the teacher with the first and last name that the user inputs, and stores it inside the students table.

Students Table **Empty Until A Student Is Entered**

```
student_id | first_name | last_name | teacher_id
```

Teachers Table

```
teacher_id | first_name | last_name
     1     |    name    |    nameLast
```

So, when the user enters a student's info with the teachers first name of `name` and last name of `nameLast`, it should get the `teacher_id` of 1 and store it in the `students table`. But it doesn't. Any ideas?

PHP Code

```
<?php

// PROCESSES STUDENT INFO

// get connect page
require '../../connect.php';

// get input info
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$teacher_first_name = $_POST['teacher_first_name'];
$teacher_last_name = $_POST['teacher_last_name'];

// check if input is not empy
if(!empty($student_id) && !empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($teacher_first_name) && !empty($teacher_last_name)) {

    // check if numeric inputs have a number
    if(is_numeric($student_id)) {
        $teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT teacher_id FROM teachers WHERE first_name='$teacher_first_name' AND last_name='$teacher_last_name'");

        if($teacher_check) {
            $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) SELECT $student_id, '$first_name', '$last_name', 'teacher_id' FROM teachers WHERE first_name = '$teacher_first_name' AND last_name = '$teacher_last_name'");

            if($result) {
                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");
            } else {
                // echo mysqli_error($link);
                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Teacher Does Not Exist");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add a number for Student ID");
    }

} else if (empty($student_id) || empty($first_name) || empty($last_name)) {
    header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add you're input values");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $first_name AND $last_name FROM teachers");
```

should be

```
$teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM teachers");
```

You should not use the dollar sign in your query to the database and as pointed out by Qirrel, replace the AND by a coma.

Comment: The columns you want to select are separated by commas, not `AND`

Comment: I changed the `$teacher_check` and got rid of the `AND`, but its still not working.

Comment: Edit your question Siddharth Nand to show the latest thing you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
$teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT $first_name AND $last_name FROM teachers");
```

To this...

```
$teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT teacher_id FROM teachers WHERE first_name='$teacher_first_name' AND last_name='$teacher_last_name'");
```

Also, please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should take necessary steps to secure your code. Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) is a good approach to take.

**Update:**

After this...

```
if($teacher_check) {
```

Add this...

```
$row = $teacher_check->fetch_object()
```

Then change this...

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) SELECT $student_id, '$first_name', '$last_name', 'teacher_id' FROM teachers WHERE first_name = '$teacher_first_name' AND last_name = '$teacher_last_name'");
```

To this...

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) VALUES ($student_id, '$first_name','$last_name', $row->teacher_id)");
```

Comment: I edited my code, but It still doesn't store the correct `teacher_id`, it stores 0 for the `teacher_id`

Comment: @SiddharthNand Please see my latest update to my answer